# How to upload multiple files after removing some files from preview PHP JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

an example  I've uploaded the 3 Image (files), In the preview, I did not like 1  file that has been deleted, rest of the files 2 and 
 it should upload 2 but  when I press submit button 3 files inserting into the database

please help me not working

**html code**

```
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <div id="filediv">
   <input name="upload[]" type="file"  id="upload" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"/>  
</form>
```

**Jquery code**

```
     function deletePreview(ele, i) {
   "use strict";

    try {
     $(ele).parent().remove();
   filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    }
  }

  $("#upload").on('change', function() {
     "use strict";


    var filesToUpload = [];

    if (this.files.length >= 1) {
    $("[id^=previewImg]").remove();
    $.each(this.files, function(i, img) {
      var reader = new FileReader(),
        newElement = $("<div id='previewImg" + i + "' class='abcd'><img /></div>"),
        deleteBtn = $("<span class='delete' onClick='deletePreview(this, " + i + ")'>delete</span>").appendTo(newElement),
        preview = newElement.find("img");

      reader.onloadend = function() {
        preview.attr("src", reader.result);
        preview.attr("alt", img.name);
      };
       var f = document.getElementById("upload").files[i];


       filesToUpload.push(f);

      if (img) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(img);
      } else {
        preview.src = "";
      }

      newElement.appendTo("#filediv");
    });
  }
});
```

**php code**

```
   $total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

  for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {

 $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
   $newFilePath = "./upload_files/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

   if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don’t see any JS code anywhere that would be responsible for the actual upload to the server. So are you submitting the form normally, no AJAX?

Comment: @04FS  yes we  don't use ajax

Comment: You can not remove any file the user chose in the file upload field via scripting. So your choices are to either let the upload of all files proceed as is, and then decide on the server side to discard some of them; or you will have to do the upload via AJAX, so that you can build the data set that gets send yourself, and leave the “deleted” files out of that.